# How do I cross-reference data from an specific column in a certain table (staging table) to confirm if exists in another?

Tags: sql, oracle

**DISCLAIMER: I'M A TOTAL SQL N00B AND THIS IS MY FIRST POST**

I'm trying to see if the data from a column on the staging table actually made it across by matching that data and see if it exists in the **PROD** table.

OK, so what I'm currently having to query the staging table to confirm if the information made it there and then I have to manually type another query to check if the data that I just confirmed made it to the staging table was correctly integrated into the **PROD** table. This can get rather time consuming and I'm sure there's a better way to do this, I just don't know how.

To query the staging table I'm simply doing this:

```
select COLUMN_A from SCHEMA.STAGING_TABLE;
```

And if everything it's there, I continue by manually typing another query like this:

```
select * from SCHEMA.PROD_TABLE where COLUMN_B = 'VALUE1' or COLUMN_B = 'VALUE2'... or COLUMN_B = 'VALUEN';
```

So I guess what I need is to construct a query that takes the value from **COLUMN_A** from **SCHEMA.STAGING_TABLE** and search for (and show) matches in **COLUMN_B** in **SCHEMA.PROD_TABLE**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the two:

```
SELECT p.columnb
FROM   schema.prod_table p
JOIN   schema.staging_table s ON p.columnb = s.columna
```

Comment: Wow! That worked like a charm at a first try. I know coding is super straight forward but I'm missing the knowledge part.

Thanks a lot for your help! You've made my mornings so much better.